# Write implementation of std::streambuf with POSIX file descriptors

Tags: c++, std, iostream

I'd like to implement a std::streambuf that uses POSIX file descriptors, such that I can use it with `std::istream` and `std::ostream`.

For `std::ostream` I only had to override `std::streambuf::xsputn` but when I impement `std::streambuf::xsgetn` for `std::istream` nothing is read from the actual file. I've looked into the implementation of `operator>>` and it seems it is not using `xsgetn` at all rather it uses `snextc` which is not marked as virtual.

My question now is what functions do I have to overload to have a complete implementation of `std::streambuf` and what parts are already handled by the base class?

My current implementation looks like this:

```
#include "fstream"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "unistd.h"

class fd_streambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    int fileDescriptor;
public:
    fd_streambuf(int fileDescriptor) : fileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
    {
    }

    ~fd_streambuf() override
    {
        close(fileDescriptor);
    }

    int sync() override
    {
        return fsync(fileDescriptor);
    }

    std::streamsize xsputn(const char* s, std::streamsize n) override
    {
        return write(fileDescriptor, s, n);
    }

    std::streamsize xsgetn(char* s, std::streamsize n) override
    {
        return read(fileDescriptor, s, n);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/tmp/test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
    fd_streambuf fd_streambuf(fd);
    std::ostream os(&fd_streambuf);
    os << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    fd_streambuf.sync();

    std::istream is(&fd_streambuf);
    std::string fileContent;
    is >> fileContent;

    assert(fileContent == "Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

When you run this "Hello, world!" is written to "test.txt" but the istream can't read it.

Comment: You have to override `underflow` and maybe `uflow`

Comment: For output you should have overridden `overflow`, you just got lucky with only overriding `xsputn`

Comment: Ok, I've looked up the spec of `overflow` on [cpp refernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) and I dont understand what should happen when `ch` is not `EOF`

Comment: If you are going for unbuffered I/O then simply output it

Comment: If you do want to manage a buffer, then 1) output existing contents of the buffer (if it exists) 2) create a buffer (if it does not exist) 3) store the given character in the buffer.